# How to handle empty node in XPATH for logstash xml filter

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, xpath, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a XML file with 100 records, in one of the record the xml node is missing as the value is not available in source system.

The xml path is like this:

```
/Envelope/Body/response/table/row/description/text
```

in other missing record the path is until here:

```
/Envelope/Body/response/table/row/description
```

The node is missing as there is no value.

How can we define the XPATH for such case

```
xpath => [
        "/Envelope/Body/response/table/row/description/text()","description"  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very rarely appropriate to use `text()` at the end of a path. Usually you want the string value of the element. Using `text()` fails if the element is empty, and it fails if the value contains comments or processing instructions. The path `/Envelope/Body/response/table/row/description` returns the element node, and in many contexts you will automatically get the string value of the element; if you need to be explicit, call the `string()` function to extract the string value. For an empty element this will be "".

Comment: how can i apply this in my logstash xpath syntax. Currently i am getting error and this record is missed

Comment: If you're getting an error then tell us what you are doing and what the error is. (I don't know logstash so I don't know, for example, what version of XPath it implements).

Comment: Hi thanks for response.Logstash uses nokogiri xml library. http://www.nokogiri.org/. Lets say i have 3 records. In the output i am getting only 2 records and 1 records is missed as 1 node is missing. In ruby code i am getting ruby exception error. I don't know much details about the error. But bottom line is that record is missed

Comment: any idea how to handle the XPATH for self closing tags

Comment: XPath isn't interested in tags, only in nodes. A self-closing tag will result in an element node having no children. That's why text() selects nothing (and why using text() is a bad idea).

Comment: This link is the reason i am using text() https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev         . With this text(), i am able to get the value for all the nodes but not for this one

Comment: You're not going to take my advice so I will stop giving it.

Comment: Okay, i did bit more research. Please suggest what else i can use apart from text(). I tried this as well              xpath => [
        "/Envelope/Body/response/table/row//description[/text() and /@attributeID]","description"  
]